# How to deploy a react repo on netlify

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I am learning to deploy different react apps on different hosting platform. So I cloned this repo [Cloned Repo](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery) and run it locally and it works fine, so I am trying to deploy it on netlify.

Based on the repo this is how I configured the build settings on netlify
[image: Build Settings]

But after It finished deploying and I preview the deployed live link, the page is just blank without any error, Though I feel it's not routing to the main page based on the project webpack.config.js, but I don't know exactly what to do?

Comment: put `/` in base directory and you need to set the publish directory according to the build config in webpack. if the webpack build directory is `dist` use that else if it is `build` use that. I don't think example is the publish directory

Comment: @the.marolie Thank you for your response. I added the `/ ` in the base directory and set the publish directory to `dist ` which is what is in the `webpack` build, and redeployed, but still no changes, the page is still blank

Comment: can you provide the link to the netlify app

Comment: also, your build command should be `npm run build` instead of `webpack`

Comment: @the.marolie Yes I am using npm run build, this is the link to the netlify app 
https://63f288a599e7cf19c729ccc4--endearing-halva-1272c6.netlify.app

Comment: @the.marolie Please have you been able to view the netlify link

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that, in netlify, you have already mentioned your publish path as `dist`. But in your index.html, you have mentioned the script src as `/dist/example.js`.

We just need to modify the script src in index.html as `example.js` instead of `/dist/example.js` since we are already inside `dist` folder.

index.html

```
<script src="example.js"></script>
```